# MDX find and replace a string

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

i'am working with MDX query i'am have a query like this :

```
SELECT non empty {[Measures].[value]} on columns, Non empty { [DimY].   [Year].[Year] } on rows  FROM myTab
```

the query return me a value like this

```
                 Value
calendar 1998      10
calendar 1999      20
```

what i want is remove the calendar string and get this result

```
              Value
     1998      10
     1999      20
```

Comment: `Calender 1998` is a member property. You can't *change* it on the fly. What you can do is have the changed value in a measure and display it along with a member from some other dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sourav has mentioned you can do something like this:

```
With MEMBER Measures.[Yr] AS
    VBA!Right([DimY].[Year].currentmember.Name,4)
SELECT 
    non empty 
        {
            Measures.[Yr]
           ,[Measures].[value]
        } ON COLUMNS, 
    Non empty 
       [DimY].[Year].[Year].members ON ROWS
FROM myTab
```

Comment: no problem - glad it helped. The drawback is that it will not be possible to get rid of the data ON ROWS  - so you will still have `calendar 1998` etc

Comment: yes i don't have problem because i will display only the column without calendar in my report thanks